# How to set unique id to multiple tags with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page where there are multiple `<section>` tags, what I want to do is to assign to each one of them an unique id.

```
<body>
<button id="set" onclick="setIds()">SET</button>
<div id="d1">
    <section>1</section>
    <section>2</section>
    <section>3</section>
    <section>4</section>
    <section>5</section>
    <section>6</section>
<div id="demo"></div>
<script>
 var sec = document.getElementsByTagName('section');

   function setIds(){ 
    for(var i = 0; i < sec.length; i++){
        console.log(sec[i].id);
        var secId = 0;
        secId += 1;
        sec[i].id = secId;
    }}
</script>
</body>
```

I'm still learning javascript, so, I've tried using this code and it just adds the same id for all sections. Any help would be much appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because each loop you reset `secId` to `0`. If you declare it outside the loop and only increment each loop, it'll work:

```
var secId = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < sec.length; i++){
    console.log(sec[i].id);

    secId += 1;
    sec[i].id = secId;
}
```

Comment: yes, and `secId` is the same as `i` so it is not even needed.

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting the `secId` each time in your `for` loop. So it's always going to be `1`. Don't do that. In fact, you don't even been `secId` at all because you have the your array index. So in your loop you could do something like:

```
sec[i].id = "section_" + i;
```

Or if you *really* want it to start at `1`:

```
sec[i].id = "section_" + (i+1);
```

I added the prefix of `section_` just because using just the number is likely to clash if you have multiple bits of code doing something similar

Comment: What if I wanted to leave just the last section without and ID?

Comment: @ELS: 1) why on Earth would it matter? And 2) just don't set the id on the last one. Loop to `i < sec.length-1` to skip the last one.

Answer (score 1):

put this line outside the loop 
var secId = 0;
cause each time you enter the looop and declare the variable and set 0 and add (1) and set to a new section